# UIView border with several colors with equal sectors

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, calayer

For example, I have a UIView and I need to make border with 3 colors.
I can do like that:

```
func addDividedColors(colors:[UIColor], width:CGFloat = 1) {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame =  CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.bounds.size)
    var colorsArray: [CGColor] = []
    var locationsArray: [NSNumber] = []
    for (index, color) in colors.enumerated() {
        colorsArray.append(color.cgColor)
        colorsArray.append(color.cgColor)
        locationsArray.append(NSNumber(value: 1.0 / Double(colors.count) * Double(index)))
        locationsArray.append(NSNumber(value: 1.0 / Double(colors.count) * Double(index + 1)))
    }

    gradientLayer.locations = locationsArray
    gradientLayer.colors = colorsArray

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.lineWidth = width
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds.insetBy(dx: width/2, dy: width/2), cornerRadius: self.cornerRadius).cgPath
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    gradientLayer.mask = shape
    self.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

but then I'll see border with 4 sectors:

[image: Output]

But It should looks like:

[image: Expectation]

Is only way - to create circle with several colours, or it can be achieved by border? 
Thanks!

Comment: This is might be Useful https://github.com/TharinduKetipe/KATCircularProgressChart

Comment: Can you please show the **insertSublayer** method?

Comment: @iPeter insertSublayer is a default method in CALayer

Comment: Ohh, so is it an extension of `CALayer` which you have written?

Comment: yes, it's an extension for CALayer

Comment: Do you want to set a static border pattern only or it should be dynamic as per required?

Comment: @iOSTeam sorry, didn't get you. I want to make border with N different colors with equal sectors like on second image.

Comment: Why are you appening the color two times consecutively?

Comment: @iPeter if you do that once, there will be a gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally did this task. Here is an extension for CALayer:

```
func addDividedColors(colors: [UIColor], width: CGFloat = 10) {
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: frame)
        var segments: [CAShapeLayer] = []
        let segmentAngle: CGFloat = 1.0/CGFloat(colors.count)
        for index in 0..<colors.count{
            let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

            // start angle is number of segments * the segment angle
            circleLayer.strokeStart = segmentAngle * CGFloat(index)

            // end angle is the start plus one segment
            circleLayer.strokeEnd = circleLayer.strokeStart + segmentAngle

            circleLayer.lineWidth = width
            circleLayer.strokeColor = colors[index].cgColor
            circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

            // add the segment to the segments array and to the view
            segments.insert(circleLayer, at: index)
            addSublayer(segments[index])
        }
    }
```

And how it looks like now:

[image]